# JMeter saving document to MongoDb with Java BeanShell: Problem in JSR223 script Sampler

Tags: mongodb, docker, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to insert once and update few times in MongoDb through JMeter. In case it is relevant MOngoDb is running in Docker. I am getting issues during connection but it seems I am trying connecting to MongoDb wrongly.

I am confident that MongoDb is up and running since I can successfuly connect and add data to it from Spring with this parameters:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port:  27017
      database: demodb
      authentication-database: admin
      username: root
      password: rootpassword
```

I have tried two approaches in JMeter and both are returning errors:

FIRST TENTATIVE)

With Lambda. I read somewhere that lambda doesn't work with Grovy but I am trying to use Java (I know nothing about Grovy). I added this detail here because when I search around people facing issues with "->" in Jmeter the answers are always related to "Grovy doesn't work with Lambda". I ignored this answer since I am using Java. At least, I assume I choose Java properly by right click Thread Group -> Sampler -> JSR 223 Sampler -> under Script Language Box I piccked up java (Bean Shell2.0b6 /Bean Shell Engine 1.0)

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;
try {
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyToClusterSettings {builder -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(                new ServerAddress(vars.get("localhost"),vars.get("27017").toInteger())))}
        .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("demodb"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("transfers"));
    vars.putObject("collection", collection);

    Document document = new Document("id", "3")
    .append("origem", "Jimis")
    .append("destino", "drpc")
    .append("status", 1);

    collection.insertOne(document);

    return "Connected to " + vars.get("transfers");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

With this approach I get this error log:

```
2020-04-03 16:11:23,519 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-04-03 16:11:23,519 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-04-03 16:11:23,520 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-04-03 16:11:23,529 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-04-03 16:11:23,529 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-04-03 16:11:23,530 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-04-03 16:11:23,530 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-04-03 16:11:23,531 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-04-03 16:11:23,533 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-04-03 16:11:23,534 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:11:23,542 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' Encountered ">" at line 10, column 103.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' at line number 10
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' Encountered ">" at line 10, column 103.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' at line number 10
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:82) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2020-04-03 16:11:23,544 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:11:23,544 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:11:23,544 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-04-03 16:11:23,545 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

SECOND TENTATIVE)

Avoiding Lambda just in case it help me move forward.

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try {
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("demodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&ssl=true");

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("demodb"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("transfers"));
    vars.putObject("collection", collection);

    Document document = new Document("id", "3")
    .append("origem", "Jimis")
    .append("destino", "drpc")
    .append("status", 1);

    collection.insertOne(document);*

    return "connected";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

And the logs are:

```
2020-04-03 16:14:18,684 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-04-03 16:14:18,685 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-04-03 16:14:18,685 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-04-03 16:14:18,746 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-04-03 16:14:18,746 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-04-03 16:14:18,746 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-04-03 16:14:18,746 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-04-03 16:14:18,747 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-04-03 16:14:18,747 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-04-03 16:14:18,747 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:14:18,752 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 16, column 46.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' at line number 16
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 16, column 46.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' at line number 16
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:82) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2020-04-03 16:14:18,753 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:14:18,753 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-03 16:14:18,753 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-04-03 16:14:18,753 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

In frist tentative it seems it is complaining to use lambda here

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyToClusterSettings {builder -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(                new ServerAddress(vars.get("localhost"),vars.get("27017").toInteger())))}
            .build();
```

And in second tentative it seems it is complaining of equals signal but I don't think my comprehansion is accurate.

```
message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; i . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 16, column 46.
```

*** Authorization issue (as far as I can see I am using the same configuration successfully logged from Spring to MongoDb

```
import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import org.bson.*

MongoCredential coreCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("root", "demodb", "rootpassword".toCharArray());
MongoClient coreMongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(coreCredential));
DB coreDB = coreMongoClient.getDB("demodb");
DBCollection coll = coreDB.getCollection("transfer");

BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject("id", "3")
.append("origem", "Jimis")
.append("destino", "drpc")
.append("status", 1);

coreDB.getCollection('transfer').insert(document);
```

New error:

```
-06 18:59:39,561 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-06 18:59:39,588 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}
javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.2.1]
```

PS.: I read somewhere I should update JMeter MongoDb jar so I did (now is mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar)

*** Other tentative

When I try

```
import com.gmongo.*;
import com.mongodb.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;                    

DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("demodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&ssl=true", "demodb");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("transfer"); 
long count = collection.getCount();
String result = String.valueOf(count);              // convert long to String

//log.info("Log Resultado:" + result)); 
SampleResult.setResponseData("SampleResult Resultado: " + result,"UTF-8");
```

I get

```
 Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You didn't define variable:demodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&ssl=true using MongoDB Source Config (property:MongoDB Source)
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You didn't define variable:demodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&ssl=true using MongoDB Source Config (property:MongoDB Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
```

It seems it is complaining about  MongoDB Source Config. Well searching on Internet I didn't found how to config it in JMeter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793119/jmeter-cant-use-java-stream-in-jsr223-script

Comment: I saw this question before. As I mentioned above I don't know Grovy. Is learning Grovy mandatory to use Jmeter with MongoDb? I don't think so. How would you accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use lambda in groovy, but you don't have to use [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793119/jmeter-cant-use-java-stream-in-jsr223-script) in your case

You can use [groovy's closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793119/jmeter-cant-use-java-stream-in-jsr223-script) or use java anonymous inner class as [example](https://gist.github.com/rozza/78f926103dad935c482b98b8ee065d90)

> ```
>  MongoClientSettings expected = MongoClientSettings.builder()
> .applyToClusterSettings(new Block<ClusterSettings.Builder>() {
>
> @Override  
>  void apply(final ClusterSettings.Builder builder){
>  builder.hosts([new ServerAddress('host1', 1), new ServerAddress('host2', 2)]);
> ```

Comment: I am trying to use Grovy but I am still stuck. Now I am getting an exception with autorization (see details pasted above)

Comment: I read someone facing issue with autentication but it seems I am doing exactly the same he did (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546319/4148175)

Comment: @JimC This is a different issue, please ask a new question

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074361/issue-while-connecting-jmeter-to-mongodb-com-mongodb-commandfailureexception

Answer (score 1):

Beanshell doesn't support [diamond operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_operator) so make sure to choose `groovy` in the "Language" dropdown.

Moreover [users are encouraged to use Groovy since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

So consider switching to Groovy and the error should go away.